# CI Test with TFS 2013 and multiple versions of Structuremap

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

#### Problem Description

We run Continuous Integration builds on a a solution that includes all of our projects. Suddenly some of our CI tests started to fail, they could not load their specific version of Structuremap. They all work fine if they are run on the developers machine, they only fail on the build server!

#### Analysis

It seems that the tests projects deploy their binaries to, and are run from the same folder. Since we have diffrent versions of Structuremap in different test projects the version that eventuely end up in the common bin directory is from the last project. Which is correct for the last project but not for all others... Have I understod things correctly?

Is it possible to instruct TFS to run the tests in their separate bin folders to allow for different versions of dll-files?

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have different versions of your structuremap referenced by different projects within a single solution. That seams to be the problem!

Comment: @MrHinsh We have different versions of structuremap because the web projects have been created during an extended period of time, each project have the version that was current when we created it. We dare not update them since they are working, and do not want to make any changes to the code.

Comment: The solution is to have consistency. The tests are correctly choking and your configuration can cause future issues. Fix the cause, don't just treat the symptoms with another bandage. All of your projects within a single solution should reference contestant versions.